# Possible Magnets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Okay so I was going through my book and found this interesting question --

Which of the following is possible? 
$a)$ a magnet with no poles 
$b)$ a magnet with two poles 
$c)$ a temporary magnet with three poles 
$d)$ all of these

I thought the answer would be $b)$ but it turned out to be $d)$.Can someone please tell me how is the first and third option correct? I really have nothing to begin with.

I've been taught magnetic poles exist in pairs so how is the answer (c) possible i.e. how can there be *a temporary magnet with three poles*? Also how is option (a) possible i.e. how can a *magnet exist without any poles*?

Comment: I've edited the question to emphasise that it is asking how a temporary magnet with three poles can exist. I also would like to know the answer to this as i don't know how it could be done.

Comment: Your question looks as a test question, because you citated your test options. I suggest to consider the close reasons of your question: 1) "ask about a specific physics concept" and 2) "show some effort".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the test question expects you to *exclude* c) because of the reasons you stated.

Comment: I would also like to know how can a magnet exist without any poles.